# Who is actually playing the game in DS9 "move along home"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the *Star Trek DS9* episode "Move Along Home" Quark is forced into a game by the aliens of the week. He rolls dice and the aliens move pieces around the board while saying if a good thing or a bad thing happened.

Meanwhile the senior officers are transported into a gameworld of some kind where they seem to be making independent decisions, every time Quark rolls the dice they face a challenge of some sort and seemingly make their own choices to overcome it, in the end Quark is faced with a choice to "sacrifice one so two may live" in the game world one of the officers is injured but the other two refuses to leave the injured one and all three end up failing the current challenge.

Ultimately who is actually playing the game? If the senior officers had been exceptionally stupid, would they have been stuck indefinitely on one of the puzzles; or if Quark had rolled exceptionally poorly could they have escaped whatever peril befell them?

Comment: The guy makes it clear (at the end) that although they thought they were fighting for their lives, it's really just a game.

Comment: I think this episode is much better than most people give it credit for. Thanks for the good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understood it as a combination of both.

The general situation was determined by the dice. The strategy (take the riskier or less risky way) by Quark and the tactics (how to handle this specific situation) by the officers.

So, no-one could've won without the other and a mistake (or bad luck with the dice) would've "killed" the entire party.